# Update canceled: attempt to update a target row with values from multiple join rows

Tags: netezza

I am getting the below issue while running a update statement:

> Update canceled: attempt to update a target row with values from multiple join rows

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when you try to update a row more than once.  Below is a simple example.

```
create temp table valuetst (
column1 varchar(10)

)
distribute on random;

insert into valuetst
select 'tstval'

update valuetst u set u.column1=aa.test
from (select 'tstval' as column1, 'asdasd' as test
union all
select 'tstval' as column1, 'number2' as test) aa
where u.column1=aa.column1
```

To avoid the error you need to make sure that you only ask the table to updated once per row.

Example of the correct update

```
update valuetst u set u.column1=aa.test
from (select 'tstval' as column1, 'asdasd' as test) aa
where u.column1=aa.column1
```