# Need SQL query to update the column using case when by joining two tables in Netezza Database

Tags: sql, database, netezza

There are 2 tables : Sales & Transaction. I need to update the INDICATOR column of the Sales table using CASE WHEN by joining these two tables in Netezza database.

Using below query but not working.
Error - Update canceled: attempt to update a target row with values from multiple join rows

```
Update Sales s 
SET indicator = 
 CASE  
     WHEN  t.retail >= s.PRICe then 'Y'
     WHEN  t.retail <  s.PRICE then 'N'
     ELSE NULL END
FROM TRANSACTION t
     WHERE s.id = t.id and s.STORE_ID = t.store_id;
```

Comment: See if this helps... 
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21179631/update-canceled-attempt-to-update-a-target-row-with-values-from-multiple-join-r

Comment: I got it that this happens when we try to update a row more than once. But is there something we can do by modifying the query? because what I understood in MYSQL that it gets updated if we uncheck the safe updates from setting. But in Netezza how do we do that?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a relationship in your where clause as one to many. Try to unique identify rows in the Sales table you want to update. Now you are trying to update one row in sales several times and the SQL engine doesn´t know which update should be correct and interrupts the update.

Comment: I got it that this happens when we try to update a row more than once. But is there something we can do by modifying the query? because what I understood in MYSQL that it gets updated if we uncheck the safe updates from setting. But in Netezza how do we do that?

Comment: Try to make select * from Sales s  join TRANSACTION t WHERE s.id = t.id and s.STORE_ID = t.store_id; And check the results, maybe its necessary add some more filters for example you could have createdDate columns in your tables and add s.CreatedDate = t.CreatedDate in where clause. Updating in the way you planning will cause unexpected results and don't give you clean information in future.